# Darts question, conditional probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, binomial-distribution

Question:

You throw 1000 darts. Each one has a 50% chance of scoring. For the first 500 darts, each is worth 1 point, and for the second 500 darts each is worth 3 points. What is the most likely number of 3-point darts you got in given that your score is 1500?

---

I've tried writing out the probability of getting m 3-point darts in given a score of 1500 but the presence of factorials makes it difficult to find the maximum. I've also thought about using a normal approximation but this also got messy - I'm wondering if there's a simpler way?

Comment: I don't see how to avoid a computation, but it's really not all that bad. For each $n\in \{0,3,6, \cdots, 498\}$  Let $p_n$ be the probability that exactly $n$ of the first $500$ score, and let $\phi_n$ be the probability that exactly $\frac {1500-n}3$ of the second $500$ score.  Then you just want to find the max of $p_n\times \phi_n$.  Should say, that $1500$ is an extremely high score on this game, so all the probabilities involved are very small.

Comment: But how do you find the maximum of an expression with factorials?

Comment: By writing them out numerically and comparing the numbers.  Honestly, I did it in Excel in less than 30 seconds.  The answer I got was $n=306$, which makes the answer to your question $\frac {1500-306}3=398$ just for comparison purposes (I wrote the computation quickly, without testing it, so it might have a bug).

Comment: Thanks! I'm just wondering if there's a way to tackle this problem without using a computer because I think it's supposed to be done by hand.

Comment: Like lulu says, it's a nasty enough function that most likely you'll have to brute force this.  You might think that 375 1-points darts plus 375 3-point darts keeps the distibutions nicely 'balanced', but both are events quite removed from the expected values .... so it'll be more likely that you have quite a few more 3-point darters than 1-point darters ... but again, where exactly that point is, is probably not easily calculated by basic analysis. I'd use some software like Excel.

Comment: Anything is possible, but I don't see a quick trick here.  I expect you could come up with a heuristic that would come close.